# Compare the days of the week in unix scripting

Tags: string, unix, if-statement, scripting

I want to compare the current day of the week and execute a set of statements depending on day.

```
to_day=$(date +%a)
if[ "$to_day" = "Sun" ]
then
 echo "Today is sunday"
 echo "First day of the week"
elif[ "$to_day" = "Mon" ]
then
 echo "Today is monday"
 echo "Second day of the week"
```

and so on...

I have tried the below if formats

```
if[$to_day = "Tue"]  
if["$to_day" -eq "Tue"]  
if["$to_day" == 'Tue']  
if["$to_day" = 'Tue']
```

But the error is still present and it reads "if[ Tue = Tue ]:Command not fount ". I have tried the above with spaces after the braces also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure in your first line is:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

and if it is in your code then make sure if: /bin and /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin directories are in you path, because all commands are here. You can check with:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

and you will get a similar answer:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/home/vivekgite/bin
```

but if you don't have those paths, you can add theirs with:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/bin:/usr/local/bin
```